# Is it okay to shut down harddisk often?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, shutdown

I have a system with two harddisks; an SSD that contains Windows 7, all the applications and most of my commonly used documents and files, and a platter-based HDD which contains the larger (media) files and projects which are usually used a few hours at a time at most.

I'd like to configure Windows to shut down the disks after 1 minute, to save power and reduce noise from the HDD (currently the loudest component in my computer). I understand this doesn't really impact the SSD in any significant way, but is it okay for the HDD to repeatedly shut it down and spin it back up again? Does it affect lifetime in any significant way? Does it really matter for power consumption?

Comment: 1 minute might be a bit extreme, depending on your usage patterns, but shutting down when not in use actually prolongs drive life.  As to power consumption it's no biggie for a desktop system but is fairly significant for a laptop on battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding power consumption, you aren't going to notice a considerable amount of power savings from it. When going in a complete read write cycle your power consumption is about 21 W, when in idle it sits around 5-6 W. 5-6W over the course of a year is only going to save you ~9 kWh if you're shutting it down from idle, so multiply that by your electricity rate to find out the expense.

The main reason to shut it down would be as you said the noise (unless you can really afford to get a different drive with a lower RPM), which may be useful to do if you find it distracting.

As for lifetime, I'd say there is most likely no hurt in shutting it down. In the old days the needle would park on the disk so there was a risk of scratches on startup, but they've fixed that and it no longer matters. In any-case pumping 5-6W of power through a circuit constantly generating heat will also wear down the components, so you'd be picking the lesser of two evils with that one.

Comment: Note: Power consumption will also depend on the efficiency of your power supply.

Answer (score 1):

There are mixed opinions on whether you extend hard drive life by turning it on and off.  If you are using it just a short time once a day for, say, backup, most people would agree that there is no reason to keep it on the rest of the time.  If you are using it all day long and powering it down every time it's idle, that's a different story.  One school of thought says doing that can be hard on a drive due to mechanical and thermal stress (expansion and contraction due to temperature changes).

On servers that are intended to be available with extremely high reliability, the drives are kept running.  The importance of doing it one way or the other may vary from drive to drive.  It wouldn't hurt to just ask the manufacturer of your drive for their recommendation.  Find their customer service or technical support contact information online.  They will be the most reliable experts for advice and may even have advice on a FAQs page.